# Highlight countries on Google Map for ios and android

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to achieve highlighting country on map.

For iOS I found few demo

[Demo1](http://sugartin.info/2012/02/13/adding-overlays-on-mkmapview-using-mkpolygon-mkpolygonview-mkoverlayview-mkannotationview/)

[Demo2](http://courseware.codeschool.com/googlemapsios/Exploring-Google-Maps-For-iOS-FULL.pdf)

But I am searching for the api that work for both ios and android.

I looked for google map api version 1.8.1.

Achieve this is only by drawing polygon on map for those certain countries?
Is there any other good way to achieve this?

Comment: did you found a solution for this? I also want to highlight all countries in the world...

Comment: did you find solution?