# How do i "select" a country with google api?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I am trying to build an *android native app* with a `world map` in which certain countries are "selected". so for example 5 countries are colored `green`, 2 countries are colored `yellow`, and the rest of the countries are `red`.

From what I found so far you have to `draw polygons`, but it's a lot of work to draw every country on earth with a polygon. **Is there a simpler way to do this?** maybe another tool or api?

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665518/highlight-countries-on-google-map-for-ios-and-android) but it was never answered.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like [this (example using Google Maps Javascript API v3 with FusionTablesLayer)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_MultiCountryBrowser.html?countries=Afghanistan,Albania,Algeria,United%20States%20of%20America,Brazil)?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46603789/6950238) answer.

Comment: I found a csv-file online that has the data i was searching for, it has the coordinates of countries borders. What i do is read the file and convert it to XML which i then later use to draw the countries.

this is the [link](https://fusiontables.google.com/DataSource?docid=1zn8cjdD6qlAFI7ALMEnwn89g50weLi1D-bAGSZw)